# Request forwarding in java

Tags: java, spring, proxy

I am writing a proxy in java/spring where requests are accepted.
Inside the proxy , the request is taken and a new request is made out of it.
This request is sent to another server and results are obtained.
And the result is sent back to the original person who requested it.
So basically instead of 
X <-> Z
The following is happening.
X <-> Y <-> Z
Here it is essential that Y should be able to filter out some results.

But then this approach is eating up a large amount of time

How can  i optimize this ?

Comment: What part of it is eating up time?  it is difficult to comment without looking at some code.  Have you run your proxy through a profiler?

Comment: What kind of filtering is Y doing?

Comment: The result of the request is a JSON. Y filters out some part of the JSON and returns back the processed JSON

Answer (score 0):

Your approach isn't very reasonable from a performance standpoint. If you want to programmatically filter the response, let the client request the actual resource and filter out the results using a servlet filter mapped to the request URL pattern.

If I may speculate that you're doing this for security reasons, I would suggest you rethink your design and perform your data security in the DB where it belongs.